# Pass command line arguments to test modules

Tags: python, pytest

When running python scripts, we can use `sys.argv` to get command line arguments and use it anywhere in our python code.

When running pytest, we can use `pytest_addoption` to add command line arguments, but it seems to me that we can only use them inside either tests or fixtures, where we can access the option through anything that exposes the `config` object.

In my case, however I would like to be able to access command line options from the test module body itself.

Is it possible to somehow access pytest's config without requiring any fixture?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have multiple ways of accessing the config object:

1. Via `request.config` attribute of the [`request`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.fixtures.FixtureRequest.config) fixture object
2. Via [`pytestconfig`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytestconfig) fixture
3. Via `pytest.config` ([the config object becomes a module attribute in the `pytest_configure` hook invocation](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/src/_pytest/main.py#L169) - use with caution in early init phase, but you can fully rely on it in tests). This is presumably what you are looking for.
4. Via `node.config` attribute of any object that subclasses [`_pytest.nodes.Node`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.nodes.Node.config), for example [`Session`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#session) object, test item nodes etc.

Example usage:

```py
# conftest.py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--spam', action='store_true', default=False, help='some flag')
```

```py
# test_spam.py

import pytest


print('accessing option on module level', pytest.config.getoption('--spam'))

def util():
    print('accessing option from non-test function', pytest.config.getoption('--spam'))


@pytest.fixture
def myfixture(request, pytestconfig):
    print('accessing option in fixture via request', request.config.getoption('--spam'))
    print('accessing option in fixture via session', request.session.config.getoption('--spam'))
    print('accessing option in fixture via pytestconfig', pytestconfig.getoption('--spam'))


def test_spam(request, pytestconfig):
    print('accessing option in fixture via request', request.config.getoption('--spam'))
    print('accessing option in fixture via session', request.session.config.getoption('--spam'))
    print('accessing option in fixture via pytestconfig', pytestconfig.getoption('--spam'))
```

etc.

Comment: Note: method 3 (pytest.config attribute) was deprecated in pytest 4.0 and removed in pytest 5.0: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62770650/243434