# None response and empty title from selenium webdriver in functional test

Tags: azure, selenium-webdriver, flask, azure-devops, pytest

I followed [this](https://elevate-org.com/2019/10/15/build-devops-ci-cd-pipeline-for-python-flask-with-azure-devops/comment-page-1/?unapproved=1825&moderation-hash=3db1fb03cab6d28e1dad6b221fbb730c#comment-1825) tutorial (Build DevOps CI/CD pipeline for Python Flask with Azure DevOps).
There is a command line task to execute a functional test which I get an error while running it.

The command line task script is as follows:

```
pip install selenium && pip install pytest && pytest Tests/functional_tests/ --webAppUrl=$(webAppUrl.AppServiceApplicationUrl) --junitxml=TestResults/test-results.xml
```

This is the script used for functional test:

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
import os
import sys
import pytest
import time

class FunctionalTests(unittest.TestCase):

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def inject_config(self, request):
    self._config = request.config

def setUp(self):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.path.join(os.environ["ChromeWebDriver"], 'chromedriver.exe'), chrome_options=options)
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(300)

def test_selenium(self):
    webAppUrl = self._config.getoption('webAppUrl')
    print ('webAppUrl:')
    print (webAppUrl)
    start_timestamp = time.time()
    end_timestamp = start_timestamp + 60*10
    while True:
        try:
            response = self.driver.get(webAppUrl)
            print (response)
            title = self.driver.title
            print ("*****")
            print (title)
            self.assertIn("Home Page - Python Flask Application", title)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print('"##vso[task.logissue type=error;]Test test_selenium failed with error: ' + str(e))
            current_timestamp = time.time()
            if(current_timestamp > end_timestamp):
                raise
            time.sleep(5)

def tearDown(self):
    try:
        self.driver.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        print('tearDown.Error occurred while trying to close the selenium chrome driver: ' + str(e))
```

I get the following error:

```
 >self.assertIn("Home Page - Python Flask Application", title):
[error]Test test_selenium failed with error: 'Home Page - Python Flask Application' not found in ''
```

When I print response it's None. And title is empty.

Can someone please help me? I'm new to pytest.

Comment: Are you running it locally or in azure CI? Can you reproduce the issue locally?

Comment: I'm running it on Azure. I can't run it locally. Whenever I try to open the URL, it prints: The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred. Not sure if this is the problem or not. I'm new to Azure App deployment.

Comment: And what is the related output in the terminal where flask server runs?

Comment: I can't see the outputs.